# Best tool for browsing schema or database properties or tabls structure of remotely installed Microsoft SQL Server by PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm seeking a tool to browse Microsoft SQL database server in PHP like phpMyAdmin. Is there any open source known project that works with Remote Microsoft SQL Server?

I found some php open source project which is incomplete or full of bug that kill my time only but I didn't get any solution.

I need to know is there any open source good and complete project for browsing MsSql database like phpMyAdmin (for MySql) that develop by PHP

Comment: As you already found a project that's "incomplete" – it seems so is your question: what exactly are your requirements? What features are needed to make it other than "incomplete"? Maybe you could [edit] your question and update it with some more precise criteria? That would enable us to (hopefully) provide you with good answers, which currently is rather impossible.

Comment: question more elaborated

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly (as I've already pointed out in my last comment). Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to build a web application. You can use SchemaCrawler to generate metadata (schema and table structure) of your remote SQL Server database in JSON format. Then, you can display this JSON data in any way you please in your PHP application.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: hmm, thanks for your response. but i don't actually try to make web application. all i want to just look into database schema. i have tool like phpmyadmin for mysql. my query was, is there any tool like phpmyadmin for mssql... anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: You can still try SchemaCrawler, which allows you to use regular expressions to look for metadata (schema and table structure), and report it in HTML.

Comment: hope it will be a good tool. i'll try it... thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/), if you don't need a web-based user interface written in PHP. SQuirreL is free and open source, and works with a remote SQL Server server to display metadata (schema and table structure), run queries, and so on.